# Realm database delete object including child objects and lists?

Tags: react-native, realm

I am using react native realm.

Deleting an object does not seem to delete lists and list item child-objects and child-lists. Should it?

I must recursively iterate through the lists, and delete listItem objects and child-lists before I can delete the root-object's list.

My work-around:

```
function dbDeleteplan(plan) {
  if (null == plan) {
    return;
  }
  console.warn('Delete plan:', plan.name);
  realm.write(() => {
    console.log('dbg: dbDeleteplan:', plan);
    if(plan.itemList) {
      for(let i = 0; i < plan.itemList.length; ++i) {
        realm.delete(plan.itemList[i].position.coords);
        realm.delete(plan.itemList[i].position);
        realm.delete(plan.itemList[i].imageList);
        realm.delete(plan.itemList[i].itemList);
      }
    }
    realm.delete(plan.itemList);
    realm.delete(plan);
  });
}
```

I expected a delete of the parent object would work but it does not:

```
   realm.delete(plan);
```

Is there a correct way to delete objects in realm?

Or perhaps I am having an async issue with a new object being created before deletion of old object had been completed?

Thanks in advance,

-Ed

Comment: Realm does not support cascade deletion out of the box, you have to delete the "child" lists manually

Comment: Thank you!  Must I also manually cascade delete objects too ?  Or only lists ?

Comment: Technically, think of "links" between objects as just links between independent objects that allow navigation from one to other.

Answer (score 0):

might this solution worked !!

```
realm.objects('plan').filtered('plan==%@', VALUE).addListener((tanplan, changes) => {

            tanplan.forEach((realmObj,index) => {                           
                realm.delete(realmObj);             
            });

        });
```